# Create a new object by cloning a set of fields defined by an interface

Tags: typescript

I have an object of class Person and an interface MoneyHolder. How to create a new object, Holder, that clones subset of fields defined  in Moneyholder?

```
class Person {
    constructor(public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public money: number) { }
}

interface MoneyHolder {
    id: number;
    money: number;
}

let person = new Person(1, 'Jack', 100);
let holder = ...????????
```

PS: I seek for an automatic solution without manual enumeration of interface fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are erased during compilation, so they don't exist at runtime, however the `Person` class is perfectly compatible with the `MoneyHolder` contract:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public money: number) { }
}

interface MoneyHolder {
    id: number;
    money: number;
}

let person = new Person(1, 'Jack', 100);
let moneyHolder: MoneyHolder = person;
```

So you can simply pass `person` where you need a `MoneyHolder` and all is well, thanks to structural typing.

## UPDATE: API Contract

If you want to represent API contracts and map fields, you could use a class:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public money: number) { }
}

interface MoneyHolder {
    id: number;
    money: number;
}

class MoneyHolder {
    public id: number;
    public money: number;

    constructor(moneyHolder: MoneyHolder) {
        this.id = moneyHolder.id;
        this.money = moneyHolder.money;
    }
}

let person = new Person(1, 'Jack', 100);
let moneyHolder = new MoneyHolder(person);
```

Or you can drop into dynamic-land, but lose all the type safety:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public money: number) { }
}

class MoneyHolder {
    public id: number = 0;
    public money: number = 0;

    constructor(moneyHolder: any) {
        for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
            this[prop] = moneyHolder[prop];
        }
    }
}

let person = new Person(1, 'Jack', 100);
let moneyHolder = new MoneyHolder(person);
```

Comment: 1) I DO need to elminate other properties because of sending data over HTTP 2)keyof is a perfect example of using interface type information in runtime https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is asking for a new object with copies of the relevant properties from the original object.  I also doubt the question means that *every* property (including `name`) should be copied, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Rem But `keyof` doesn't let you do anything at runtime.  It only exists at design time.  If you check the compiled JavaScript there won't be anything corresponding to `keyof` in there.

Comment: @Rem you didn't really supply that information in the question, but I have happily updated the answer to support it.

Comment: "clone set of fields defined by an interface" - isn't  it a precise definition of what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Type information (including interfaces) gets erased when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript.  So you can't refer to `MoneyHolder` at runtime, in order to enumerate the `id` and `money` keys you care about.

What you *can* do is create an array of the keys you care about, and TypeScript can use the type of that array to *infer* a `MoneyHolder` type for you.  Here's how to get TypeScript to infer an array of string literals:

```
function stringLiteralArray<K extends string>(...arr: K[]): K[] {
  return arr;
}
const moneyHolderKeys = stringLiteralArray('id', 'money');
```

The helper function `stringLiteralArray()` does the inference for you.

---

(Aside)

*If you just did this:*

```
const moneyHolderKeysOops = ['id', 'money']; // string[]
```

*it would be inferred as `string[]` which loses the key information you care about.  You could do this:*

```
const moneyHolderKeysTedious = ['id', 'money'] as ('id'|'money')[];
```

*but that's tedious and repetitive.  That's why we created the `stringLiteralArray()` helper function.*

---

So now you have the `moneyHolderKeys` array with an inferred type of `('id' | 'money')[]`.  Here's how you write your generic cloning function:

```
function clonePart<T, K extends keyof T>(keys: K[], obj: T): Pick<T, K> {
  const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>;
  keys.forEach(k => ret[k] = obj[k]);
  return ret;
}
```

Note the return value, `Pick<T,K>` which is a supertype of `T` specifying only the keys of `K`.  It is part of the standard TypeScript library, and its definition is:

```
/**
 * From T pick a set of properties K
 */
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

Now you can use it:

```
let person = new Person(1, 'Jack', 100);
let holder = clonePart(moneyHolderKeys, person);
```

If you examine `holder` you will see it is of type `{id: number, money: number}`.  Hey, that's `MoneyHolder`!  We can now name it if you want:

```
type MoneyHolder = typeof holder;
```

So that works.  It's a bit backwards from what you asked for, but it gets the job done without any repetition.  You can [see it in action in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28public%20id%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20money%3A%20number%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20stringLiteralArray%3CK%20extends%20string%3E%28...arr%3A%20K%5B%5D%29%3A%20K%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20arr%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20moneyHolderKeys%20%3D%20stringLiteralArray%28%27id%27%2C%20%27money%27%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20clonePart%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%28keys%3A%20K%5B%5D%2C%20obj%3A%20T%29%3A%20Pick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20ret%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Pick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20keys.forEach%28k%20%3D%3E%20ret%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bk%5D%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20ret%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20person%20%3D%20new%20Person%281%2C%20%27Jack%27%2C%20100%29%3B%0D%0Alet%20holder%20%3D%20clonePart%28moneyHolderKeys%2C%20person%29%3B%0D%0Atype%20MoneyHolder%20%3D%20typeof%20holder%3B).  Hope that helps; good luck!